# GA4 stopped tracking events enabled under Enhanced Measurement

Tags: google-analytics

Outbound link clicks are not shown on real time report and the free form report I created.

Same with other events enabled under Enhanced Measurement, they all started to drop on June 30.

I already checked Enhanced Measurement settings, and it looks alright. What could be the problem here?

[image]

Comment: What is the code you implemented for the events? Have you made changes to it?

Comment: I had the exact same issue, but noticed they started tracking again as of August 2nd.